# Parsing the date format: "Wdy, DD-Mon-YY HH:MM:SS GMT" to struct Date in D language

Tags: date, d

I have a date in this formart: `Wdy, DD-Mon-YY HH:MM:SS GMT` that I need to parse and convert it to `struct std.date.Date` or equivalent to. I have written a very simple function by using `split()`s calls(check out below my code).

The problem is performance -- I'm looking for a faster algorithm to do it. After split in tokens, I'm using `to!int(tok)` to convert to `int` and so put into struct. Is there a best way to do it? Do please suggest built-in D functions or some external module, if not too complex.

Note: I'm a C programmer starting in D programming language. So, you'll see some of C-way solutions.

```
struct MyDate {
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;
  int hour;
  int minute;
  int second;
  //int ms;

};

int index_of_month(string mont) 
{

  immutable string[] months = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];

  for(int i = 0, len = months.length; i < len; ++i)
    if(months[i] == mont) 
      return i;

  return -1;
}

void main()
{
  //date format Wdy, DD-Mon-YY HH:MM:SS GMT
  string d = "Sun, 24-Aug-2014 15:00:24 GMT";
  string[] parts = split(d, " ");
  string[] _date = split(parts[1], "-");
  string[] _hour = split(parts[2], ":");

  debug { 
    for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i)
      writefln("[%d]: %s", i, parts[i]);

  } else {

    //Handling erros goes here
    //...

    //I write my onw date struct because
    // std.date.Date cannot be compiled 
    // even by using -d flag; and std.datetime.Date is not equivalent to.
    // NOTE: I think that I will have problems when try to compare it 
    // to Clock.currTime()..
    MyDate date;

    //as you can seed below, I did a lot of 
    // string to integer conversion;
    // I don't know much aboud D, but I think
    // that it's so slow. I'm looking for a best 
    // solution(in perfomance questions).
    date.day    =  to!int(_date[0]); // 0 .. 31 min/max 2 digits.

    //I know about enum Month from std.datatime;
    // but there is no(as far as I know) equivalent to Enum.GetValues()/Enum.GetNames()
    // of C#.NET and .indexOf(), so I write my onw implemantation...
    date.month  =  index_of_month(toLower(_date[1])); // 1 .. 12 min/max 2 digits.

    //maybe do it by using e.g(C-way), 
    // int n = 0; n = (n * 10) + (_date[2][0] - '0'); n = (n * 10) + (_date[2][0] - '0'); and so..
    // and lave the compiler do promotion 
    // can be better?
    date.year   =  to!int(_date[2]); // min 2, max 4 digits. 
    date.hour   =  to!int(_hour[0]); // 0 .. 23 min/max 2 digits.
    date.minute =  to!int(_hour[1]); // 0 .. 59 min/max 2 digits.
    date.second =  to!int(_hour[2]); // 0 .. 59 min/max 2 digits.

    writefln("date.day = %d\n"
         "date.month = %d\n"
         "date.year = %d\n"
         "date.hour = %d\n"
         "date.minute = %d\n"
         "date.second = %d\n",
         date.day, date.month,
         date.year, date.hour,
         date.minute, date.second);


  }

}
```

Comment: Are you aware that std.date is deprecated and there is a better std.datetime? ( http://dlang.org/phobos/std_datetime.html )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what I've come up with:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.format;
import std.string;
import std.datetime;
import std.algorithm;

enum MONTHS = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];

int month_to_index(string month) {
    return cast(int)MONTHS.countUntil(month.toLower());
}

void main() {
    string date = "Sun, 24-Aug-2014 15:00:24 GMT";

    string a;
    int day;
    string month;
    int year;
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
    string tz;

    date.formattedRead("%s, %d-%s-%d %d:%d:%d %s", &a, &day, &month, &year, &hour, &minute, &second, &tz);

    DateTime dt = DateTime(year, month.month_to_index(), day, hour, minute, second);

    writeln(dt);
}
```

`std.datetime` really needs some kind of `strptime` and `strftime`.

Comment: "std.datetime really needs some kind of strptime and strftime" It's on the todo list, but the exact design hasn't been sorted out yet and other things have been higher priority, so it hasn't happened yet. It will at some point though.